# How can ask login if it write on url

Tags: php, html, mysqli

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-wrapper">

  <form action="#" method="post">
    <h3>Login here</h3>

    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="text" name="user" required="required" placeholder="Username" autofocus required></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="password" name="pass" required="required" placeholder="Password" required></input>
    </div>

    <div class="button-panel">
        <input type="submit" class="button" title="Log In" name="login" value="Login"></input>
    </div>
  </form>
  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);

            $query      = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  password='$password' and username='$username'");
            $row        = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $num_row    = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            if ($num_row > 0) 
                {           
                    $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
                    header('location:home.php');

                }
            else
                {
                    echo 'Invalid Username and Password Combination';
                }
        }
  ?>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my page for login the system. When the username and password is then it will go to home pages. It work properly.  but if I write in browser after log out. 
**localhost/logg/home.php** it is automatically go to that pages it not asking for login. So How to make proper login page where it asking log or automatically it will go login panned  for all the pages is that is connected with home page.

**home.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Client Management System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css/style_entry.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css/home_menu.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css/container.css" />

</head>

<body style="background-color:gray"/>



<div class="container">

 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Entry</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="marketInfo.php">Market Information</a>
      <a href="bankInfo.php">bank Information</a>
      <a href="clientInfo.php">Client Information</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="Edit.php">Edit</a>
  <a href="billProcess.php">Bill Process</a>
  <a href="billPrint.php">Bill Print</a>
  <a href="billPosting.php">Bill Posting</a>
  <a href="report.php">Report</a>
  <a href="admin.php">Admin</a>
  <a href="help.php">Help</a>
  <a href="help.php">Help</a>
  <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>


</body>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location:index.php');
?>
```

**How can I secure it ?? how can I set if I write the url in browser then it will automatically go to the login page.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a file 'login_check.php'

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
}else{
 header("location:login.php");
}
?>
```

include this file in those pages which should only be accessible to logged in user.

Comment: its working. Is this login is secure from sql injection ??

Comment: you are already using mysqli_real_escape_string(), so it is somewhat secure from sql injection

Comment: How can I set a time limit ? After login the system if it not get any refresh  10 minutes then it automatically go to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** On top of every page you need to check session is exists or not . if session exists allow user to see the page otherwise redirect the page to login page .

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){

  header('Location:login.php');
  exit();
}
```

Note : Session is globally accessible variable . Based on that you need to make logic .